# Can't recognize xml in eclipse project

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I want to create an xml file under src. i've created it through choosing file option and named it with .xml extension. but when i call this file from main program it can't find that xml file and shows error.
[image: Screenshot of my project window]

Answer (score 0):

The option XML is depending on what plugins you have installed on eclipse, but anyways xmls are not folders but instead files with xml formatted content... so if you dont see the xml folder just tell the wizard you want a new file:

[image]

and be sure that the file has a valid xml content

Comment: I've tried that too which i've posted in the edited version of my question but still there is problem.